# Interpretation of my GLZ output

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have done a GLZ model for to find the relationship of my categorical predictor variable (palatability.score) and my continuous response variable (Impact). 
My output is as such:

---

```
**glm(formula = Trees$ï..Impact. ~ Trees$Palatability.score.)
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
   -4.566   -3.676   -2.804   -0.424  271.502  
Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  4.3465     0.3689  11.782   <2e-16 (3 stars)
Trees$Palatability.score.2  -0.6242     0.5600  -1.115    0.265 
Trees$Palatability.score.3   0.2192     0.6209   0.353    0.724

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 169.8508)

Null deviance: 490016  on 2885  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 489680  on 2883  degrees of freedom
AIC: 23014
Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2**
```

---

I am trying to interpret this data and am having trouble as only the intercept is significant. 
I have however figured out the palatability cannot alone indicate the impact, but now how do I explain the relationship between palatability and impact of my 3 categorical groups if my group 1 palatability score is the intercept?
- I have made the equations for score 2 and score 3 as such:
Impact = 4.346 - 0.6242(Palatability.score.2)
Impact = 4.346 + 0.2192(Palatability.score.3)
how do I how get the equation for my palatability score 1?
- Is it just Impact = 4.346 + 0(Palatability.score.1)???

Can anyone please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if we could see your data, because how you encoded the categorical variable in the data is important to the interpretation of your model.

Did you encode the categorical variable via. one hot encoding? Then your interpretation is probably correct; in the presence of Palatability.score.2 (indicated by a one or zero) we expect a negative influence of 0.6242  units on impact. In the presence of Palatability.score.3, we expect a positive influence of 0.2192 on impact.

Your equation you modeled is this (assuming you used a regular identity link, ie. a typical linear regression):

Impact = 4.3465 + Palatability.score.2 * -0.6242 + Palatability.score.3 * 0.2192

If you encoded the categorical variable palatability in your data correctly (and assuming that palatability.score.X is a discrete variable that categorizes an observation into in this case three distinct categories) then in your data for one observation you should have three columns to represent this variable; one column for Palatability.score.1 (assuming this group is the desired reference) that is a dummy column (all zeros or all ones generally) and two other columns; Palatability.score.2 and Palatability.score.3 (both being typical 0,1 indicator variables). If for one observation, the group is palatability.score.1, then for one row all three of the columns should be zeros, implying that the expected impact should just be the intercept (the reference category). If for score 2, one row should be encoded as 0,1,0 implying an expected impact of

4.3465 + -0.6242 * 1 + 0.2192 * 0 = 3.7223

and for  score 3, one row should be encoded as 0,0,1 implying an expected impact of

4.3465 + -0.6242 * 0 + 0.2192 * 1 = 4.5657.

I hope this helps.